# Need query logic in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table called `product` like this:

```
source_item_id source_rev_id  
----------------------------
111              a_01_tz
111              b_01_tz
111              c_01_tz
222              e_02_tz
222              f_02_tz
222              g_01_tz
333              h_03_tz
444              g_04_tz
```

Now I want output in this format:

```
source_item_id source_rev_id  target_rev_id
--------------------------------------------
111              a_01_tz       AAA
111              b_01_tz       AAB
111              c_01_tz       AAC
222              e_02_tz       AAA
222              f_02_tz       AAB
222              g_01_tz       AAC
333              h_03_tz       AAA
444              g_04_tz       AAA
444              l_04_tz       AAB
```

For one `source_item_id`, there can be multiple `source_rev_id`'s.

Please help in the query writing. Thanks.

Comment: Either for source_item_id 222 you have wrong values or I don't understand the logic. I see AAA twice

Comment: you sample seems whitout logic to me ..

Comment: So you want to tack on a field with three characters? Please describe what should be happening.

Comment: So... where do these target_rev_ids come from? I can kind of reverse-engineer the logic, but then `222` doesn't make any sense. did you fat finger that in the sample?

Comment: @JNevill That's what I was thinking. If 222              f_02_tz       AAA, is supposed to be 222              f_02_tz       AAB then I can see the pattern.

Comment: sorry my mistake its for source_rev_id value is 
222              f_02_tz       AAB 
actually target_rev_id  earlier i changed to AAA for all Source_rev_ids of  source_item_id..now my requirement is for every each source_rev_id , values should be updated as given in the required output.

Comment: If that is the pattern then something fun like `CHAR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY source_item_id ORDER BY source_rev_id) + 64)` and then some extra math-iness to click over to the next position. Perhaps some base26 madness.

Comment: Thanks, @gpr. I've retracted my close vote. This is an interesting question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quite a hard thing to do with SQL but there is a next_permutation function used in cpp to get the next permutation of a string for instance, so its something like next_permutation of AAA is AAB you apply it each time you find the same item_id.

Answer (score 5):

Combine a subquery to create an item counter and an expression to create `AAA` to `ZZZ` from the counter:

```
SELECT    
 source_item_id, source_rev_id ,
   CHAR( (target_rev_num)/676 % 26 + 65)
 + CHAR( (target_rev_num)/26  % 26 + 65)
 + CHAR(  target_rev_num      % 26 + 65)
 AS target_rev_id
FROM (    
  SELECT source_item_id, source_rev_id ,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY source_item_id 
                             ORDER BY source_rev_id ) -1
         AS target_rev_num
  FROM product
) P
```

Comment: That's beautiful.

Comment: Great answer, but lest future readers be confused, you didn't actually use a CTE.   You used a derived table.  Which, by the way, you need to alias.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to create a permanent lookup table of all the target_rev_ids you might have, with an id column, like

```
1   AAA
2   AAB
3   AAC
4   AAD
5   AAE
```

etc.

Then you can just join to that table with the ROW_NUMBER function.